# Axios 2 post requests - use response of first post in second request?

Tags: reactjs, api, post, axios

With Axios I am trying to:

1. a post request that has a successful response (or that has error, return error)
2. if first request sucessful, use a returned value in the response, and post to second request to different endpoint

Nearest thing I had was:

```
import axios from 'axios';

let one = "https://api.storyblok.com/v1/cdn/stories/health?version=published&token=wANpEQEsMYGOwLxwXQ76Ggtt"
let two = "https://api.storyblok.com/v1/cdn/datasources/?token=wANpEQEsMYGOwLxwXQ76Ggtt"
let three = "https://api.storyblok.com/v1/cdn/stories/vue?version=published&token=wANpEQEsMYGOwLxwXQ76Ggtt"

const requestOne = axios.get(one);
const requestTwo = axios.get(two);
const requestThree = axios.get(three);

axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
  const responseOne = responses[0]
  const responseTwo = responses[1]
  const responesThree = responses[2]
  // use/access the results 
})).catch(errors => {
  // react on errors.
})
```

But this does calls at once, so I can't pass value to second post, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case this is not applicable as the second api call is dependent on the first api call result.

I would suggest making the first call with `async-await` to wait till the response comes back and then make the second call using that.

Try something like this :

```
async function callApis(){
let responseOne = await fetch("/endpointOne");
// Check for response and if successful call the second api
let responseTwo = await fetch("/endpointTwo");
}
```

In short, wait for the first api to finish before calling the second api.

Hope it helps!

Edited to use fetch. I am not clear as to you wanted to use `axios` or not.

Answer (score 2):

So came across this and trying out:

```
axios.get(`/endpoint`) 
.then(
  responseA =>
    Promise.all([
      responseA,
      axios.get("/endpointB")
    ])   
)
.then(
  ([responseA,responseB]) => {
  console.log(responseA,responseB);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
});
```